# Sheafification of a presheaf through the etale space

Tags: sheaf-theory

I have some problems to show that the following construction defines a sheafification:

Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf on $X$, and let $Et(\mathcal F)$ be the etale space associated to $\mathcal F$, with $\pi:Et(\mathcal F)\rightarrow X$ that is the canonical map which sends a germ $s_x$ to $x$. If with $U$ we indicate a generic open set of $X$, then the set of sections of $\pi$ on $U$ is
$$\mathcal F^+(U)=\{\,\widetilde s:U\rightarrow Et(\mathcal F)\ \ \text{with}\ \ \widetilde s(x)=s_x\;\forall s\in \mathcal F(U)\,\}$$
We give a certain topology on $Et(\mathcal F)$ and make $\pi$ and $\widetilde s$ continuous functions. In this way we define the sheaf $\mathcal F^+$ of continuous sections of $\pi$, and the morphism (for all $U$)
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(U):\mathcal F(U)&\rightarrow& \mathcal F^+(U)\\
s&\mapsto& \widetilde s
\end{eqnarray}
Now if $\mathcal F^+$ satisfies the "universal property", it is the sheafification of $\mathcal F$. Suppose that $\psi$ is a morphism from $\mathcal F$ in a generic sheaf $\mathcal G$; how can I prove that there exists a unique morphism $\theta:\mathcal F^+\rightarrow\mathcal G$ such that $\theta\circ\phi=\psi?$

Comment: One way to do it is to show that there is a natural bijection between sheaf morphisms $\mathscr{G} \to \mathscr{H}$ and bundle morphisms $\textrm{Ét}(\mathscr{G}) \to \textrm{Ét}(\mathscr{H})$, or equivalently, that there is an isomorphism from the sheaf of sections of $\textrm{Ét}(\mathscr{G})$ to the sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ itself.

Comment: a natural way would be to define $\theta(\widetilde s)=\psi(s)$ but what about the uniqueness?

Comment: That formula does not obviously define $\theta$ – you have to check that it makes sense. As usual, uniqueness is actually the easy part: once you convince yourself that there is a $\theta$, notice that $\phi$ is surjective on stalks, so if $\theta$ and $\theta'$ are sheaf morphisms, then $\theta \circ \phi = \theta' \circ \phi$ implies $\theta = \theta'$.

Comment: You're right, $\theta(\widetilde s)=\psi(s)$ doesn't define a function because if  $s_x=t_x$ for all $x$, doesn't imply that $s=t$. This because $\mathcal F$ is a presheaf.

Comment: Crossposted to MO [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97400/sheafification-of-a-presheaf-through-the-etale-space).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Definition 1.**
Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf of sets (or abelian groups or rings, etc.) on a topological space $X$.
Let $Et(\mathcal F)$ be the disjoint union $\cup_{x \in X} \mathcal F_x$.
Let $U$ be an open subset of X.
Let $s \in \mathcal F(U)$.
We denote by $[U, s]$ the subset {$s_x; x \in U$} of $Et(\mathcal F)$.
Let Open$(X)$ be the set of open subsets of $X$.
We define a topology on $Et(\mathcal F)$ as the one generated by the subset {$[U, s]; U \in$ Open($X), s \in \mathcal F(U)$} of the power set of $Et(\mathcal F)$.
Let $\pi:Et(\mathcal F) \rightarrow X$ be the canonical map which sends a germ $s_x$ to $x$.
Let $\mathcal F^+(U)$ be the set {$f:U \rightarrow Et(\mathcal F)$; $f$ is a continuous map and $\pi f = id_U$}.
Clearly $\mathcal F^+(U)$ defines a sheaf $\mathcal F^+$ on $X$.

**Lemma 2.**
Let $\mathcal F^+(U)$ be as above.
Then $\mathcal F^+(U)$ = {$f:U \rightarrow Et(\mathcal F)$; $f$ is a map such that for each $x \in U$ there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ contained in $U$ and $s \in \mathcal F(U_x)$ such that $f(y) = s_y$ for each $y \in U_x$}.

Proof: Clear.

**Definition 3.**
Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf on a toplogical space $X$.
Let $U$ be an open subest of $X$.
Let $s \in \mathcal F(U)$
We define a map $\tilde{s}: U \rightarrow Et(F)$ by $\tilde{s}(x)$ = $s_x$ for each $x \in U$.
Clearly $\tilde{s} \in \mathcal{F^+(U)}$.

**Definition 4.**
Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf on a toplogical space $X$.
Let $U$ be an open subest of $X$.
We define a map $\iota_U: \mathcal F(U) \rightarrow \mathcal F^+(U)$ by $\iota_U(s) = \tilde{s}$, where $\tilde{s}$ is defined in Definition 3.
Clearly $\iota_U$'s define a morphism $\iota:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F^+$.
We call $\iota$ the canonical morphism.

The following lemma is fundamental.

**Lemma 5.**
Let $\mathcal F$ be a sheaf on a topological space $X$.
Then the canonical morphism $\iota:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F^+$ is an isomorphism.

Proof:
Let $U$ be an open subest of $X$.
It suffices to prove that $\iota_U: \mathcal F(U) \rightarrow \mathcal F^+(U)$ is an isomorphism.
Let $s$ and $t$ be $\in \mathcal F(U)$.
Suppose $\iota_U(s)$ = $\iota_U(t)$.
This means that $s_x$ = $t_x$ for each $x \in U$.
Hence there exists an open neghborhood $U_x$ of $x$ for exch $x \in U$ such that $s|U_x$ = $t|U_x$.
Since $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf, $s$ = $t$.
Hence $\iota$ is injective.

It remains to prove that $\iota$ is surjective.
Let $\sigma \in \mathcal F^+(U)$.
There exists an open cover $U_i$ of $U$ and $s_i \in \mathcal F(U_i)$ such that $\sigma(x) = s_i(x)$ for each $x \in U_i$.
Since $s_i|U_i \cap U_j = s_j|U_i \cap U_j$ by the above claim, there exists $s \in \mathcal F(U)$ such that $s|U_i$ = $s_i$ for each $i$.
Hence $\iota(s)$ = $\sigma$, so $\iota$ is surjective.
**QED**

**Lemma 6.**
Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf on a toplogical space $X$.
Then $\mathcal F^+_x$ = $\mathcal F_x$ for each $x \in X$.

Proof: Clear.

**Lemma 7.**
Let $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ be presheaves on a topological space $X$.
Let $f:\mathcal F \rightarrow G$ be a morphism.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$.
Let $\sigma \in \mathcal F^+(U)$.
Then the map $f^+_U(\sigma):U \rightarrow G^+(U)$ which sends $x \in U$ to $f_x(\sigma(x))$ for each $x \in U$ belongs to $\mathcal G^+(U)$.

Proof: Clear.

**Lemma 8.**
Let $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ be presheaves on a topological space $X$.
Let $f:\mathcal F \rightarrow G$ be a morphism.
Let $\iota_{\mathcal F}:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F^+$ and $\iota_{\mathcal G}:\mathcal G \rightarrow \mathcal G^+$ be the canonical morphisms.
Then there exists a unique morphism $f^+:\mathcal F^+ \rightarrow \mathcal G^+$ such that
$f^+\iota_{\mathcal F} = \iota_{\mathcal G} f$.

Proof:
We have the canonical morphism $f_x:\mathcal F_x \rightarrow \mathcal G_x$ for each $x \in X$.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$.
We define a map $f^+_U:\mathcal F^+(U) \rightarrow \mathcal G^+(U)$ by sending $\sigma \in \mathcal F^+(U)$ to $f^+_U(\sigma) \in \mathcal G^+(U)$, where $f^+_U(\sigma)$ is defined in Lemma 7.
Clearly this gives a morphism of presheaves $f^+:\mathcal F^+ \rightarrow \mathcal G^+$ and $f^+\iota_{\mathcal F} = \iota_{\mathcal G} f$.

It remains to prove the uniqueness of $f^+$.
Let $\psi:\mathcal F^+ \rightarrow \mathcal G^+$ be a morphism such that
$\psi\iota_{\mathcal F} = \iota_{\mathcal G} f$.
Since $\mathcal F^+_x$ = $\mathcal F_x$ by Lemma 6, $\psi_x$ = $f^+_x$ for each $x \in X$. Since $\mathcal F^+$ and $\mathcal G^+$ are sheaves by Definition 1, $\psi$ = $f^+$.
**QED**

**Proposition.**
Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf on a toplogical space $X$.
Let $\mathcal G$ be a sheaf on a toplogical space $X$.
Let $f:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal G$ be a morphism.
Then there exists a unique morphism $\theta:\mathcal F^+ \rightarrow \mathcal G$ such that
$\theta\iota$ = $f$, where $\iota:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F^+$ is the canonical morphism.

Proof:
This follows immediately from Lemma 5 and Lemma 8.

Comment: I am uncertain about the characterization of the topology in Def 1. If our etale space is, say, a trivial line bundle over the real line, then sets like $[U,s]$ don't seem to be open. For example, if we take the diagonal section $d$ and the zero section, then $d^{-1}([U,0])$ is just the origin, so $d$ wouldn't be continuous.