# On sheafification and stalks

Tags: sheaf-theory

I have a problem but it may be easy for you.
So, please give me a lecture.
Thank you.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a presheaf on a topological space $X$ and ${}^a\mathcal{F}$ a sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$:

${}^a\mathcal{F}(U):=\{s:U\to \bigoplus_{x\in X}\mathcal{F}_x\ |\ s\text{ is a section of }\pi:\mathcal{F}_x\ni a\to x\in X\}$,

where $U$ is an open set in $X$ and $\mathcal{F}_x$ is a stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ associated with $x\in U$.

I understood that ${}^a\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf, but I did not understand that $({}^a\mathcal{F})_x \simeq \mathcal{F}_x$ for any $x\in X$.
According to some texts, it is clear by definion. Why?

Comment: Where did you get that definition from? First time I see it. When I was introduced to it we defined ${}^a\mathcal{F}(U)$ as a subset of $ \prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_x$. It's maybe the same thing, I'm just curios.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about your condition in the set. A section of a morphism is usually something like this: you have $\pi:A \to B$ and $s:B\to A$ with $\pi\circ s=id_B$. But in your condition  $s$ and $\pi$ don't map to the same spaces. Can you clarify?

Comment: As remarked by @Maik, your definition of ${}^a\mathcal{F}(U)$ is completely false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sheafification of a presheaf through the etale space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146996/sheafification-of-a-presheaf-through-the-etale-space)

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, your description of $\mathcal{F}^a$ is not completely correct. First, it should be the disjoint union instead of the direct sum of the $\mathcal{F}_x$. Then all sections of $\pi$ are not allowed, only those that satisfy this condition :
$$ (1) \quad \forall x\in U, \exists V\ni x \text{ a neighborhood of $x$ in $U$ and }t\in\mathcal{F}(V) \text{ such that } \forall y\in V, s(y)=t_y $$
Otherwise you have too many sections, for example, if $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{C}$ is the sheaf of continuous function on a space $X$, with your definition a section in $\mathcal{F}^a$ would consists of the choice of a germ of continuous function at every point, without conditions that these germs glue (and they might define a function which is not continuous).

Hence the good definition is the following :
$$\mathcal{F}^a(U)=\{s:U\rightarrow\coprod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_x | s \text{ is a section of $\pi$ and satisfies condition $(1)$}\}$$

---

Now it is easy to see that $\mathcal{F}^a_x=\mathcal{F}_x$. Indeed, if $s_x$ is a germ of a section in $\mathcal{F}^a_x$, then you can find a representative $(U,s)$ where $s\in\mathcal{F}^a(U)$. Now by condition $(1)$, there exists $t\in\mathcal{F}(V)$ such that $\forall y\in V, s(y)=t_y$. But this implies that $(U,s)$ and $(V,t)$ define the same germ. So $s\in\mathcal{F}_x$.

To be perfectly rigorous, check that what I just described is a well-defined map $\mathcal{F}^a_x\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_x$ which is the inverse of the obvious map $\mathcal{F}_x\rightarrow\mathcal{F}^a_x$.

Comment: How does $(U,s)$ and $(V,t)$ define the same germ? They live in different spaces.

Comment: @AlJebr The explanation was given in the line just below. Is it not clear ?

Comment: I'm sorry, where is the explanation? I see that $s$ lives in $\mathcal F^a(U)$ but $t$ lives in $\mathcal F(V)$. How can $(U,s)$ and $(V,t)$ define the same germ if the direct limit is taken over different spaces? I guess I should ask: What do you mean by they define the same germ?

Comment: @AlJebr The explanation was "To be perfectly rigorous, check that what I just described is a well-defined map $\mathcal{F}^a_x\to\mathcal{F}_x$ which is the inverse of the obvious map $\mathcal{F}_x\to\mathcal{F}^a_x$." What I meant is the class of $(V,t)$ is a germ in $\mathcal{F}_x$, and the canonical map $\phi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}^a$ maps this germ to a germ in $\mathcal{F}^a_x$ which is still represented by $(V,t)$ (or rather $(V,\phi(t))$). Then $(U,s)=(V,\phi(t))$ in $\mathcal{F}^a_x$ and the map $(U,s)\to (V,t)$ well defined and the inverse of $\phi$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think I get it now. This is all new to me so I think I was getting thrown off by the abuse of notation. I'm not used to it yet. I think I see it now though. Thanks.

Comment: I'm now learning about the inverse image sheaf and it is very heavy notation since we have direct limit of direct limit. Any advice on how to deal with all this notation?

Comment: @AlJebr You should ask a separate question with a clear explanation on where are your difficulties. Just a piece of advise : don't use the direct limit of direct limit definition, and use mainly the adjunction property.

Comment: I think it should be infinite product not infinite coproduct here...

Comment: @Chris Do you mean an infinite product in the definition of $\mathcal{F}^a$ ? Well no, it really is a coproduct there. Did I misunderstood your comment ?

Comment: @Roland Yes I mean infinite product in the definition of $F^a$. If it is infinite coproduct then finitely many of the $s_x$ in the element $(s_x)$ are non zero which would be bad for sections no?

Comment: @Chris As I said in the answer, this is not the coproduct in the category of abelian groups, this is the disjoint union (in other words, the coproduct in the category of sets). But read carefully the construction : $\mathcal{F}^a(U)$ is not the coproduct. This is rather the set of maps from $U$ into the coproduct which satisfies two conditions. The first one means that for each $x\in U, s(x)\in \mathcal{F}_x$ (where $\mathcal{F}_x$ is a subset of $\coprod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_x$ in the obvious way, but this is really a disjoint union here).

Comment: But this is true that $\mathcal{F}^a(U)$ can be seen as a subset of $\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_x$ (and this time I mean product). But, sections of $\mathcal{F}^a(U)$ are not maps from $U$ to the product. There are several ways to write this set. I used "map into the coproduct" way instead of the "product" way because this was closer to what the OP had in mind and also because the second condition is better written with this notation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the topology of the etale space. It is the coarse topology such that for every $s\in {\cal F}(U)$, $s:U\rightarrow {}^a{\cal F}$ where $s(x)$ is the image $s_x$ of $s\in {\cal F}_x$ is continue. A base open subset of ${}^a{\cal F}$ is defined by $\{s_x\in {\cal F}(U)\}$ where $s$ is an element $s\in {\cal F}$.

Consider the map $f:{}^a{\cal F}_x\rightarrow {\cal F}_x$ such that for every $u\in {}^a{\cal F}_x$, take a section $s\in {}^a{\cal F}(V), V\subset U$ such that $u$ is the image of $s$ in ${}^a{\cal F}_x={\cal F}_x$. There exists $t\in {\cal F}(W)$ such that $u=t_x$. Write $f(u)=t_x$. $f$ is well-defined, if you consider $t'\in {\cal F}(W')$ such $t'_x=u=t_x$, there exists $A\subset W, A\subset W'$ such that the restriction of $t$ and $t'$ to $A$ are equal this implies that $f$ is well defined.

$f$ is surjective: for every $u\in {\cal F}_x$, consider $s\in {\cal F}(U)$ whose image in ${\cal F}_x$ is $u$, $t:U\rightarrow {}^a{\cal F}$ defined by $t(y)=s_y$ is an element of ${}^a{\cal F}(U)$, and the image of the element in ${}^a{\cal F}_x$ induced by $t$ by $f$ is $u$.

$f$ is injective. Suppose that $f(u)=f(v)=t_x$, without restricting the generality, we can suppose that there exists $s,s'\in{}^a{\cal F}(U)$ whose image in ${}^a{\cal F}_x$ is respectively $u$ and $v$. Remark that the map $p:U_t=\{t_x,x\in U\}\rightarrow U$ defined by $p(t_x)=x$ is injective. Write $W=s^{-1}(U_t)\cap{s'}^{-1}(U_t)$, it is an open subset which contains $x$, we deduce that the restriction of $s$ and $s'$ to $W$ are equal since $p$ is injective. This implies that $u=v$.

Answer (score 0):

I use the notation in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146996/sheafification-of-a-presheaf-through-the-etale-space).

We want to show that for any $x\in X$, $ \phi_x$ is bijection.

**injectivity**:
Let $ \phi_x(s_x)= \phi(t_x)$ 
(where $s\in \mathcal{F}(U), t\in \mathcal{F}(V)$).

Since $ \phi_x(s_x)=(\tilde{s})_x, \phi_x(t_x)=(\tilde{t})_x$, $\tilde{s}|_W=\tilde{t}|_W$ for some open neighbourhood $x\in W\subset U\cap V$ by definition of germ. So for any $p\in W$, $(p, s_p)=\tilde{s}(p)=\tilde{t}(p)=(p, t_p)$, therefore $s_p=t_p$. Especially, you get $s_x=t_x$, 
considering a case $p=x$.

**surjectivity**:
Take arbitrary $s_x\in \mathcal{F}^{+}_x$ 
(where $s\in \mathcal{F}^{+}(U)$). 
We write $s(x)=(x, t_x)$(where $t\in \mathcal{F}(V)$), then by continuity of $s$ on $U$, for some open neighbourhood $x\in W\subset U$ such that $s(W)\subset [V, t]$ since $[V, t]$ is open neighbourhood of $s(x)$. That is, for every $y\in W$, $s|_W(y)=s(y)=(y, t_y)$. 
therefore we get $ \phi(V)(t)|_W=s|_W$ and, 
\begin{align}
    s_x
    =( \phi(V)(t))_x
    = \phi_x(t_x)
    \in \operatorname{Im}  \phi_x. 
\end{align}